# Where can I find an extensive list of Wilderness Kids products?

Tags: ubiquity, hollow-earth-expedition

*[Hollow Earth Expedition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollow_Earth_Expedition)*'s Ubiquity System was expanded into a game called *[Wilderness Kids](http://mythiceras.net/index.php?option=com_content&task=blogsection&id=11&Itemid=30)* targeted to younger gamers giving them an introduction to roleplaying and the Ubiquity rules. The resources available seem to be in disarray. Where can I find a complete list of adventures and supplements for *Wilderness Kids*?

Comment: Surprisingly, RPGGeek doesn't have anything on this game yet.

Comment: Right! I first looked there, too.

Comment: Might be time for me to create some more official Wilderness Adventure Kids material. I am hoping that perhaps 2012 will be the year of the Wilderness Adventure Kid. I may put all other adventures (Six Guns of Death & Dirk Savage) to really get the WAKids up and going.

Comment: I haven't created any new Wilderness Kids (now Wilderness Adventure Kids) material in quite some time. This year at GENCON 2015, we'll be unveiling the latest two hour WAKids adventure (Monkey Mayhem AKA MONKEY MAYHEM AT THE ZOO). Originally planned for release in 2010 it got bumped for another project that year. It's a few years late, but we expect it to be a lot of fun. If we see sold out games, and more people asking for material I will reconsider the idea of talking to the Exile Games folks about some more adventures in what I would like to call the KIDbiquity line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the following is the list of Wilderness Kids adventures and their first appearance at Gencon:

1. Movie Mayhem ('08)
2. Haunted House ('09)
3. Jewels of Prometheus Falls ('10)
4. Mummy Menace in the Museum ('10)
5. Monkey Menace at the Zoo ('10)
6. Revenge of the Saucer-Men ('10)
7. Tentacles of Terror ('10)
8. Treasure Trouble ('10)
9. Save Christmas ('11)

So far, only Movie Mayhem is complete at the Mythic Eras Site.  My draft version of the WK Save Christmas is also there.  The original and my "alternate" version of the PC's are also at Mythic Eras site.

Answer (score 2):

Well, here's the thing. *Wilderness Kid Adventures* is not officially a separate RPG.

What it is is an idea spawned in someone's feverish mind to create adventures geared towards the younger set using the Ubiquity system. There have been a few runs created, most if not all unveiled in GenCons past.

The runs have been very well received (I believe this year's GenCon will feature at least one new adventure). It'd be great to point to some resource where the adventures were available for public consumption, but since this is really a labor of love, publication has been a bit spotty.

What is available can be obtained from the [Mythic Eras site](http://mythiceras.net/index.php?option=com_content&task=blogsection&id=11&Itemid=30). Perhaps if a general outcry for more material is heard, the authors will feel more confident to release more of their fine creations. ;-)

Comment: Here's my +1 outcry!